# Bash: Content between two complex Patterns - html

Tags: html, bash

I have tried multiple times to get digits between two html patterns.
Neither `sed` nor `awk` worked for me, since the examples in the internet were too easy to fit my task.

Here is the code I want to filter:

```
....class="a-size-base review-text">I WANT THIS TEXT</span></div> ....
```

So I would need a command that output: `I WANT THIS TEXT` between `...review-text">` and `</span>`

Do you have a clue? Thanks for the effort and greetings from Germany.

Here is the plain [code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12K46GUAvCuT2hdTuPtWdNFyLQ0DoBkAbPH6IlHxmXg4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share what you have tried, and explain why they didn't work.

Comment: [You shouldn't use regex for (X)HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/404556), but a real xml parser like `xmllint`. If you provide more details of your html structure, we might help you to write the xpath query.

Comment: Hi randomir: Here is the html file code: ibb.co/iNSDXb -- Thanks for the effort!

Comment: That's an image you posted there! Please see how to write [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is my own solution: cat source.html | tr -d '</>"' | grep -o 'review-text[^<>]*spandivdiv' | awk -F 'review-text' '{ print $2 }' | awk -F 'spandivdiv' '{ print $1 }'

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem here supposing the text you want to extract doesn't contains < nor >.
For instance with POSIX REGEXP:

```
$ HTML_FILE=/tmp/myfile.html
$ sed -n "s/.*review-text.>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/gp" $HTML_FILE
```

prints the text between HTML TAGS

Comment: ----- It is a html source from a product review link. All I want is the Review Text itself. And as I said it is between those two patterns. Filtering the whole html file with your command did not work for me...

Comment: I updated my answer to extract all the text from a file instead of a single variable.

Comment: I needed to use sed -E instead of -r because im on OSX. Anyways it did not work as intended. sed gives me a huge list instead of only print the text between the two patterns. Thanks for the effort tho

Comment: @MultiF 95 you can use this simple regular expression command. It worked on the file supplied in your link:  sed -n "s/.*review-text.>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/gp" $HTML_FILE

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tr '\n' ' ' file.html | grep -o 'review-text">[^<>]*</span> *</div>' | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f 1
```

It should work if there are no any tags inside "I WANT THIS TEXT"

Comment: Terminal says that I don't use tr correctly. Im on a Mac. Thats the fault?

Comment: On my linux machine tr command works, as expected. I can't test it on Mac now. You can try any other tool (sed,awk). First, change every end-of-line character to space, next pipe output to grep with -o option. It should works